# TweenMax: tween stumbles the first time

Tags: actionscript-3, animation, tween

I have some image Containers which hold a lot of images(10-100).
Some of those Containers(Sprites) are off screens but are loaded and added.
Through arrow keys I start a tween in the according direction.
The tween is not smooth(stumbles) always the first time when a container comes on-screen.
How do I get a smooth tween ?

Comment: If the tween is smooth after the first time, your problem could be the excess of animations at the same time right from the start. Could you describe a little more your scenario?

Comment: There is grid of images(about 100 small ones(60x60px)) visible on the start screen. When I press an arrow-key, an other grid of images (from the outside of the stage) will be tweened to be visible…

Comment: Can you post a link to your source, or at least, a link to a demo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mySpriteContainer.cacheAsBitmap = true;
-> solved my problem